# How to scrape data from list of URLs and save data to CSV with nokogiri

Tags: ruby, csv, nokogiri

I have a file called bontyurls.csv that looks like this:

```
http://bontrager.com/model/11383
http://bontrager.com/model/01740
http://bontrager.com/model/09595
```

I want my script to read that file and then spit out a file like this: bonty_test_urls_results.csv

```
url,model_names
http://bontrager.com/model/11383,"Road TLR Conversion Kit"
http://bontrager.com/model/01740,"404 File Not Found"
http://bontrager.com/model/09595,"RXL Road"
```

Here's what I've got so far:

```
# based on code from here: http://www.andrewsturges.com/2011/09/how-to-harvest-web-data-using-ruby-and.html

require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'

@urls = Array.new
@model_names = Array.new

urls = CSV.read("bontyurls.csv")
(0..urls.length - 1).each do |index|
  puts urls[index][0]
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(urls[index][0]))
  doc.xpath('//h1').each do |model_name|
    @model_name << model_name.content
  end
end

# write results to file  
CSV.open("bonty_test_urls_results.csv", "wb") do |row|
  row << ["url", "model_names"]
  (0..@urls.length - 1).each do |index|
    row << [
      @urls[index], 
      @model_names[index]]
  end
end
```

That code isn't working. I'm getting this error:

```
$ ruby bonty_test_urls.rb 
http://bontrager.com/model/00310
bonty_test_urls.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /home/simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:239:in `block in each'
    from /home/simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:238:in `upto'
    from /home/simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:238:in `each'
    from bonty_test_urls.rb:14:in `block in <main>'
    from bonty_test_urls.rb:11:in `each'
    from bonty_test_urls.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

Here is some code that returns the model_name at least. I'm just having trouble getting it to work in the larger script:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://bontrager.com/model/09124"))
doc.xpath('//h1').each do |node|
  puts node.text
end
```

Also, I haven't figured out how to handle the URLs that return a 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I'd do it:

```
require 'csv'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

CSV_OPTIONS = {
  :write_headers => true,
  :headers => %w[url model_names]
}

CSV.open('bonty_test_urls_results.csv', 'wb', CSV_OPTIONS) do |csv|
  csv_doc = File.foreach('bontyurls.csv') do |url|
    url.chomp!
    begin
      doc = Nokogiri.HTML(open(url))
      h1 = doc.at('h1').text.strip
      h1 = doc.at('title').text.strip.sub(/^Bontrager: /i, '') if (h1.empty?)
      csv << [url, h1]
    rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => e
      csv << [url, e.message]
    end
  end
end
```

Which generates a CSV file like:

```
url,model_names
http://bontrager.com/model/11383,Road TLR Conversion Kit (Model #11383)
http://bontrager.com/model/01740,404 File Not Found
http://bontrager.com/model/09595,RXL Road (Model #09595)
```

Comment: @pguardiario, it's `wb` in the OP's question. Sometimes CSV data contains 8-bit characters so I preserved that setting.

Answer (score 0):

You declare @model_names, but try to push in to @model_name, which is why it's nil.